# how to determine if 2 dates object equals each other?

Tags: javascript, date

this is my 1st question in stackoverflow.

```
var str="Oct 13,2011";
var date1=new Date(str);
var date2=new Date(str);
```

of course
valueOf(date1)==valueOf(date2)

but why
date1!=date2

or say,how to determine 2 date object if they equal each other.

Date is a js object

Comment: Minor nitpicking: Javascript is case-sensitive, this should be `new Date()`, capital `D`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript objects are only equal if they refer to the same object-reference. Which is not the case in your code.

*(reference: [What is the standard definition of object equality for "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229312/what-is-the-standard-definition-of-object-equality-for))*

Edit: With a little type casting you can do:

```
var str="Oct 13,2011";
var date1 = new Date(str);
var date2 = new Date(str);

console.log(+date1 == +date2); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

`==` or `===`  compares object references.

Date1 and date 2 are created from different references. Therefore, they are not equal.

convert your date1 and date2 to primitive data type and compare

`date1.getTime()=== date2.getTime()`

Result : True

Answer (score 1):

Using `==` does not work in general as it compares object [identities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692863/what-is-the-difference-between-identity-and-equality-in-oop) not values.

Using the `+` prefix or `getTime()` to convert to milliseconds before comparison can also fail in the case your date objects have a time component and you only wish to compare their date portions. (Do not be tempted to reach for the `toDate()` method as that is day of month, and discards month and year!).

This seems to be one of the few times that `toDateString()` is useful, for a succinct solution without the use of additional libraries.

```
var date1=new Date("2014-12-10");
var date2=new Date("2014-12-10T01:00");

+date1 == +date2
>false

date1.getTime() == date2.getTime()
>false

date1.toDateString() == date2.toDateString()
>true
```