# Two identical JavaScript dates aren't equal

Tags: javascript, date

When I create two identical JavaScript `Date` objects and then compare them, it appears that they are not equal. How to I test if two JavaScript dates have the same value?

```
var date1 = new Date('Mon Mar 11 2013 00:00:00');
var date2 = new Date('Mon Mar 11 2013 00:00:00');
console.log(date1 == date2); //false?
```

[JS Fiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/QEqhU/result/)

Comment: also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244513/javascript-date-comparisons-dont-equal)

Comment: To see if two dates are equal, you could do `+a == +b` or `!(a - b)`, but that may be a bit obfuscated. Don't leave parsing random date strings to the Date constructor, either provide a standards compliant string (which isn't consistently supported yet) or provide values per [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It appears [this has been addressed already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753297/how-to-determine-if-2-dates-object-equals-each-other?rq=1).

To check whether dates are equal, they must be converted to their primitives:

```
date1.getTime()=== date2.getTime()
//true
```

Answer (score 23):

First of all, **you are making a sound mistake here in comparing the references.** Have a look at this:

```
var x = {a:1};
var y = {a:1};

// Looks like the same example huh?
alert (x == y); // It says false
```

Here, although the objects look identical they hold different slots in memory. Reference stores only the address of the object. Hence both references (addresses) are different.

So now, we have to compare the values since you know reference comparison won't work here.
You can just do

```
if (date1 - date2 == 0) {
    // Yep! Dates are equal
} else {
   // Handle different dates
}
```

Comment: Good answer - especially because I find date.GetTime() misleading (suggests it will get the time to me (even though I know there isn't a time object))

Answer (score 0):

I compare many kinds of values in a for loop, so I wasn't able to evaluate them by substracting, instead I coverted values to string before comparing

```
var a = [string1, date1, number1]
var b = [string2, date2, number2]
for (var i in a){
  if(a.toString() == b.toString()){
    // some code here
  }
}
```