# Checking if date belongs to array of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date

I'm trying to check if a date from a jQuery UI datepicker belongs to an array of dates that are holidays. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong :(

```
var holidayArray2013 = [new Date('October 3, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200'), new Date('December 25, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100'), new Date('December 26, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100')];
var DateOfOrder = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
if ($.inArray(DateOfOrder, holidayArray2013) > -1) {
  console.log("is holiday");
}
```

edit: `console.log(DateOfOrder);` returns `Thu Oct 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200` just like `holidayArray2013[0]` but `$.inArray(DateOfOrder, holidayArray2013)` still returns `-1`

Comment: Nor can we unless you tell us if there is an error, or perhaps not giving the result you expect.

Comment: What is the value of `DateOfOrder`?

Comment: You are looking for two seperate objects even though they may be the same date. You will need to store the dates as a string and search for  a string (one possible way).

Comment: When you `console.log` it executes `toString` on the date object.

Comment: Have a look at [Two identical JavaScript dates aren't equal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15470403/218196).

Comment: If you want a small library that can perform date comparisons, rather than writing POJS (but in this case why not?) then take a look at moments.js: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: It is actually different, you say October, DateOfOrder is Oct

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're getting a false negative because comparing 2 date objects compares their *references* and not their *values* as you perhaps expected.

There are a few options, you could store the result of `Date.getTime()` in your array which is just a numerical representation of the date:

```
var holidayArray2013 = [
        new Date('October 3, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200').getTime(), 
        new Date('December 25, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100').getTime(), 
        new Date('December 26, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100').getTime()];
```

And then compare that:

```
var DateOfOrder = n$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate').getTime();
if ($.inArray(DateOfOrder, holidayArray2013) > -1) ...
```

This works fine, as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/rRJer/

If, however you are constrained to not changing the holiday array you could loop to try to locate the right date value:

```
var isHoliday = false;
for(var i=0;i<holidayArray2013.length;i++){
    if(holidayArray2013[i].getTime() == DateOfOrder.getTime()){
        isHoliday = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/3R6GD/

Comment: thanks jamie, accepted this for being the most precise answer and providing an alternative i needed.

Answer (score 1):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/WNYRs/

```
var holidayArray2013 = [new Date('October 3, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200').getTime(),
                        new Date('December 25, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100').getTime(),
                        new Date('December 26, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100').getTime()];
```

And use something like that:

```
var DateOfOrder = new Date($('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val()).getTime();
```

you have to use `Date.getTime()` to compare two dates, see this : [How to compare two date values with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004178/how-to-compare-two-date-values-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.valueOf()` function over your dates, then the `$.inArray` will do the job :

```
var holidayArray2013 = [
    new Date('October 3, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200').valueOf(),
    new Date('December 25, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100').valueOf(),
    new Date('December 26, 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100').valueOf() ];

var DateOfOrder = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate').valueOf();
if ($.inArray(DateOfOrder, holidayArray2013) > -1) {
    console.log("is holiday");
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mmeRD/