# for daterange picker in the form how to set isinvalid date when already applied the callback function for getting the dates on click of apply button

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

List item

html form

```
<div class="form-group " id="input-dates">
<input class="form-control date-range-picker" id="dateRange_n" type="text" name="dates" placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('when'); ?>.." autocomplete="off" required>
<i class="icon_calendar"></i>
```

i have used the callback function

```
    function myCallback(start, end) {
                $('#dateRange_n').html(start.format('MM DD, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MM DD, YYYY'));

        }
    let options = {} // you can add more options to this, but need at least this
$('#dateRange_n').daterangepicker(options, myCallback)
  .on("input change", function(e) {
      var days = e.target.value;
    console.log("Date changed: ",days); });
```

now i want to use isinvalid date function for disable particular date. i have used the following function on document.ready()

```
 $('#dateRange_n').daterangepicker({
// you can use this optionally -> maxSpan: 50
 
"startDate": today,
 "endDate": today2,
 "minDate": today,
 isInvalidDate: function(ele) {
    var currDate = moment(ele._d).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    return ["06-15-2021"].indexOf(currDate) != -1;
}
```

});

it is working but callback function is not working when i add the above function on document ready

Comment: ```callback function is not working``` Which callback function is not working? There are 3 callback functions in the codes.

Comment: function myCallback(start, end) {
                $('#dateRange_n').html(start.format('MM DD, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MM DD, YYYY'));

        }
    let options = {} // you can add more options to this, but need at least this
$('#dateRange_n').daterangepicker(options, myCallback)
  .on("input change", function(e) {
      var days = e.target.value;
    console.log("Date changed: ",days); });
this callback function

Comment: Please see my answer. The callback works and you can see the console.log("callback") running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the callback function after the option.

**Example below**

```js
function myCallback(start, end) {
  console.log("callback");
  $("#dateRange_n").html(
    start.format("MM DD, YYYY") + " - " + end.format("MM D, YYYY")
  );
}

let options = {
  startDate: "12-01-2018",
  endDate: "12-01-2023",
  minDate: "10-06-2021",
  isInvalidDate: function (ele) {
    var compareDate = moment(ele);
    var startDate = moment("12/01/2019", "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var endDate = moment("5/06/2021", "DD/MM/YYYY");
    return compareDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate);
  },
};

$("#dateRange_n").daterangepicker(options, myCallback);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<div class="form-group" id="input-dates">
  <input
    class="form-control date-range-picker"
    id="dateRange_n"
    type="text"
    name="dates"
    placeholder="test...."
    autocomplete="off"
    required
  />
  <i class="icon_calendar"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: can i give range to isInvalidDate to disable the number of dates

Comment: @PriyankaPatil, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36350827/14032355 does this help?

Comment: i want to disable particular date range just like 10-06-2021 to 15-06-2021

Comment: @PriyankaPatil, I updated my answer. please see if this is what you want.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply but i have to fetch date range from database using ajax & then i have to disable that range. in the database i am having more than 1 date range

Comment: @PriyankaPatil, I think you should create another question for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i have created another question for this