# javascript date comparison not working, even in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with a javascript date comparison.  I can output the objects in the console and everything looks right, but they always evaluate to false.

```
var date1 = new Date('2013','01','01'); 
var date2 = new Date('2015','01','01'); 
console.log("date1=" + date1);
console.log("date2=" + date2);
console.log("date1 > date2" + date1 > date2);
console.log("date1 < date2" + date1 < date2);

>>date1=Fri Feb 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
>>date2=Sun Feb 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
>>false
>>false
```

Comment: `"date1 > date2" + date1 > date2`  --- what does this mean? You append a `date1` to a string, then compare the compound string and another date? It makes no sense.

Comment: Um, parenthesis around the comparisons duh?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 a comma instead of `+`

Comment: in the `console.log` context, the `+` is concatenating. Use comma instead of plus.

Comment: @zerkms That also works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two identical JavaScript dates aren't equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470403/two-identical-javascript-dates-arent-equal)

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

> Operator precedence determines the order in which operators are evaluated. Operators with higher precedence are evaluated first.

This makes a string with `"date1 > date2"` and `date1` and compares it with `date2`:

```
"date1 > date2" + date1 > date2
```

This makes a string with `"date1 > date2"` and the comparison of `date1 > date2`:

```
"date1 > date2" + (date1 > date2)
```

Also you shouldn't compare date objects directly.